# Can I switch React Native app from Yarn to NPM seamlessly or is it more involved?

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, yarn-workspaces

I am now in charge of an app whose dependencies were installed using yarn. I am more familiar with NPM. Is switching over as easy as deleting the yarn.lock file and installing NPM to the project? The app hasn't been updated in a year or two so I'm trying to update everything.

Or maybe a better question is, can I install both NPM and yarn globally but pick and choose which one I use for what app? Will it cause issues if they are both installed globally on machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can definitely have Yarn and NPM installed on the same machine without issue. NPM generally comes packaged with Node, so most people using Yarn will also have NPM installed, wether they use it or not.

In terms of switching a project from Yarn to NPM, it's a pretty straightforward process, like you described: remove `yarn.lock` and remove the existing `node_modules` directory just to avoid any issues.

The subtle issue here is that the `yarn.lock` will be the current source of truth for exactly which versions of each dependency (and sub-dependencies) is installed. So by removing the `yarn.lock` your `package.json` will now become the (incomplete) source of truth which will likely result in some dependencies being upgraded when you perform your first `npm install` -- then your `package-lock.json` will become the new strict source of truth.

Given you're planning on updating everything anyway, then this likely isn't going to be an issue, but it's worth keeping in mind as you're likely to see some minor dependency changes.

Comment: Thank you!! Very helpful answer. Now in your experience, given what I am trying to do, do you think it would be more worth it to switch to NPM or continue with yarn? I've never used yarn before, that's why I wanted to switch. @levi

Comment: @ttsssss sorry for the slow reply, I assume you've probably made a decision already but if not, you'll probably find there's almost no practical difference between them beyond some slightly different commands.

Switching to NPM is straightforward: delete `yarn.lock`, `node_modules` and then run `npm install`. Then verify the app boot and you're all done.

In the unlikely event that the app doesn't boot or has errors, then it probably means that the versions defined in your `package.json` are too permissive and need to be restricted slightly to be closer to what was originally installed.

Comment: @ttsssss this could also be a good opportunity to get familiar with using Yarn as it's likely that you'll encounter it again in the future. React and React Native both use Yarn, and there's only a few commands that you'd need to be familiar with to effectively maintain a project. Personally I primarily use Yarn for work and my own projects, but I use NPM daily when working on OSS.